# Wordpress Theme Install Issue

Tags: wordpress, templates, wordpress-theming, themes

I just downloaded a template from the website called http://randthemes.com. All the templates are rather old (from 2015), however they are free and I would like to install one of them on my Wordpress website.

The template seems to be missing quite a bit of files, however every template on this website is missing the same files. I feel that there must be something I'm missing, as in a proper way to install this that I'm not aware of. Unfortunately the support team at this website stopped responding to emails in 2016.

Something else odd is the main files in the template are in `.html`, where most templates have the files in `.php`. I have a picture below for reference:

[image: Wordpress Template Files]

Could you help me, please?

Comment: This is not a WordPress theme, @entreprenerds mentioned this is a HTML template. You need to translate this HTML files into a WordPress theme if you really want to this HTML template to be act as a WordPress Theme.

Answer (score 0):

Rand Themes says "Get free WordPress and Twitter Bootstrap templates or read articles for web development". It looks like you've downloaded a Bootstrap template, not a WordPress theme.